# Dispatch an action when a route become active

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, ngrx

I have several routes each with a table that should load data from the server.
How can I dispatch an action to the ngrx/store to load data from the server when a route with table become active?

Thanks

Comment: What router version? What Angular2 version? Adding some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish or what you have tried wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [@ngrx/router-store](https://ngrx.io/guide/router-store) that dispatches actions on different lifecycle steps.

Then add an effect that listen to `ROUTER_NAVIGATED` for example filters on a specific location and dispatches the needed loading action.

```
@Effect()
$routerNavigated = this.actions$.ofType(ROUTER_NAVIGATED)
.pipe(filter(action => (/persons/g).test(action.payload.url)),
map(action =>  new LoadSomePersonsData()));
```

Comment: Could you update the link please? It is broken. BTW, thanks for the answer. ^_^